# Using a join to return multiple values of the same column?

Tags: mysql, sql

The problem is that I'm using a table that has more than one reference to another table; basically I'm storing three different values for the original artist of a song, if it is featuring another artist, and if it is a remix or not. Each of these link to the artist table and what I want is to be able to return the artist name (no other data) for each of these columns. I have this so far:

```
SELECT `songName`, `songTrackNumber`, `artist`.`artistName`,
songFeaturingArtist, songRemixByArtist
FROM `song`
LEFT JOIN artist ON songArtist = artistID
```

I'm not entirely sure how to convert the other two fields from their numeric ID to the name of the artist. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join table `Artist` on table `song` three times to get the `artistName` for all the other columns on table song.

```
SELECT  a.songName, 
        a.songTrackNumber, 
        b.artistName AS ArtistName,
        c.artistName AS FeaturingArtist,
        d.artistName AS RemixByArtist
FROM    song a
        LEFT JOIN artist b ON a.songArtist = b.artistID
        LEFT JOIN artist c ON a.songFeaturingArtist = c.artistID
        LEFT JOIN artist d ON a.songRemixByArtist = d.artistID
```

Comment: Brilliant, I wasn't aware you could left join and give the table a different alias. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome. By the way, if these columns (`songArtist`, `songFeaturingArtist`, `songRemixByArtist`) are *non-nullable*, use `INNER JOIN` since it is faster than `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: one more thing, backtick aren't required on the column names even if you are using reserved keyword because an alias was provided on every table names.

Comment: Going to use `LEFT JOIN` because the other columns are usually `NULL`, but of course important if they contain a value. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: @JW: excellent point about qualifying column references with a table alias (`a.artistName`).  That's the normative pattern for ANY query that references more than one table. A big advantage is that it insulates a working query from breaking (throwing an "ambiguous column" error) when columns are added to tables referenced in the query.

Comment: @spencer7593 Yeah, got it from you. Don't like about more arguments `:D`

Answer (score 3):

Just keep adding joins, but by using table aliases to keep MySQL happy:

```
SELECT `songName`, `songTrackNumber`, 
    `a1`.`artistName` AS mainArtistName,
    `a2`.`artistName` AS songFeaturingArtistName,
    `a3`.`artistName` AS songRemixByArtistName
FROM `song`
LEFT JOIN artist a1 ON songArtist = a1.artistID
LEFT JOIN artist a2 ON songFeaturingArtist = a2.artistID
LEFT JOIN artist a3 on songRemixByArtist = a3.artistID
```

For clarity you could change the aliases to something more useful than a simple numeric suffix :)

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer! +1